# Show $\frac{z}{1-z^2} + \frac{z^2}{1-z^4} + \frac{z^4}{1-z^8} + \, ...$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z| > 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that the series
$$\frac{z}{1-z^2} + \frac{z^2}{1-z^4} + \frac{z^4}{1-z^8} + \, ...$$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z| > 1$ (provided $z^{2^n} \neq 1$ for any $n$.)

I'm not sure how to proceed. If we let

$$a_n = \frac{z^{2^{n-1}}}{1-z^{2^{n}}}\text{,}$$

I can see that we can look at the ratio between terms to get

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{z^{2^{n-1}}(1-z^{2^n})}{(1+z^{2^n})(1-z^{2^n})} \\
& = \frac{z^{2^{n-1}}}{(1+z^{2^n})} \\
& = \frac{1}{(z^{-2^{n-1}}+z^{2})}
\end{align}$$

which will tend to $\frac{1}{z^2}$ as $n \to \infty$, provided $|z| > 1$. Then, $|\frac{1}{z^2}| < 1$ itself, so by the ratio test this should converge.

However, I am unsure on how it is that I show the limit is $\frac{1}{1-z}$ in particular - how would I show this?

Comment: Maybe using the partial fraction decomposition
$$\dfrac{z^{2^{n-1}}}{1 - {z^{2^n}}} = -\dfrac{1}{2\Bigg(z^{2^{n-1}} + 1\Bigg)} -\dfrac{1}{2\Bigg(z^{2^{n-1}} - 1\Bigg)}$$
would help?